# OOP - Accessing Object Data

Tags: python, oop, smartsheet-api

Apologies if this is a repeated or simple question.

I have recently been learning Python (having spent many years writing simple MATLAB scripts). I've started exploring Object Oriented Programming and JSON.

I am trying to use an API to collect data from a server. When the objects are returned I'm mostly doing fine with using syntax to access particular data fields. However, I'm struggling with one. I have a row object:

```
row = {"totalCount": 1, "results": [{"parentObjectId": 887, "contextData": ["Row 1"], "parentObjectType": "sheet", "objectId": 599, "text": "Text", "parentObjectName": "Data", "objectType": "row"}]}
```

I am trying to access the "objectId" attribute for the single result (`result[0]`).

I have tried `rowId = row.results[0].objectId` but get the error "'SearchResultItem' object has no attribute 'objectId'".

I have also tried `rowId = row.results[0]['objectId']` but get the error "'SearchResultItem' object has no attribute '`__getitem__`'".

--- EDIT:

```
print(reportingRow.results[0]['objectId'])
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-46-14e026c273e3>", line 1, in <module>
   print(reportingRow.results[0]['objectId'])

TypeError: 'SearchResultItem' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

I am using a tool called Smartsheet. I am using the search_sheet request. The API documentation (http://smartsheet-platform.github.io/api-docs/#search-sheet) says that 'SearchResultItem' is an object containing a number of attributes. It doesn't give much more information.

The Smartsheet models are found here: https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/tree/master/smartsheet/models. I am currently looking at search_result.py and search_result_item.py to find the answer/clues.

--- END OF EDIT

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Your object is not a dictionary (it's only something that looks like it when you print it). Your error clearly says that it's a `SearchResultItem`. We do not know what kind of interface `SearchResultItem` implements, therefore we cannot help you.

Comment: Let us know what is the `SearchResultItem`, it is not a json string nor a dict.

Comment: Please provide the whole response from API from where your fetching data, and then lets us know where there's issue.

Comment: I have edited the original post to try and answer your questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your library code clearly says, that `SearchResultItem` has [a property `.object_id`](https://github.com/smartsheet-platform/smartsheet-python-sdk/blob/master/smartsheet/models/search_result_item.py#L108).

```
print(reportingRow.results[0].object_id)  # this works just fine
```

Your problem is not dictionary/JSON-related because you **are not** using dictionaties. You are using custom objects wrapped around those dictionaries.

Comment: Thank you Lukasz. My lack of knowledge/experience means that it was not obvious to me. Out of interest, is there any reason that when I print the row it says "objectId" as the attribute yet "object_id" is used to access the data?

Comment: For future reference: any attributes described in the Smartsheet API documentation (which do not specifically appear in a Python code example) represent how the attributes appear in the raw API (JSON) requests/responses. The Python SDK itself uses Python variable naming conventions: "lowercase with words separated by underscores as necessary to improve readability" (as described here: python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008). For example, the raw API response may contain the attribute "modifiedAt" -- but when using this attribute via the Python SDK, you'll refer to it as "modified_at".

Comment: Thanks Kim. What's confusing is that for some objects the attributes in the raw API response can be used to access the data. Perhaps previously I have only been using the attributes that are single words and so the Python naming convention and raw API response match.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
rowId = row['results'][0]['objectId']
```

Comment: It's clearly not that - OP's object is not a dictionary.

Comment: I have tried this and it does not work. Thank you for the suggestion though.